# Is it possible to use Kentico's staging API to pull serialized object information from a target server?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

We have a large, complex Kentico build which uses Kentico's Continuous Integration locally, and Kentico's Staging module to push Kentico object changes through various environments.

We have a large internal dev team and have found that occasionally (probably due to Git merging issues) certain staging tasks aren't logged. When dealing with large deployments this is often not obvious until something breaks on the target server.

What I'd like is to write a custom module which can pull certain data from a target server (e.g. a collection of serialized web parts). I can then use this to compare with the source server to identify where objects are not correctly synchronized. I'd hoped this might be possible using the web services already exposed by Kentico which handle the staging sync tasks.

I've been hunting through a few namespaces in the Kentico API (`CMS.Synchronization`, `CMS.Synchronization.WSE3` etc.) but it's not clear if what I'm trying to do is even possible. Has anyone tried anything similar. If so, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own code/tool for this I'd suggest taking advantage of what someone else has already done.  This is like Red Gate's SQL Compare for Kentico BUT on steroids.  It compares, database data, schema AND file system changes on staging and target servers.

[Compare for Kentico](http://www.bizstreamtoolkit.com/products/compare)

Comment: Thank you Brenden. I was aware of this and have to confess, I was hoping to avoid the cost of a commercial tool. To be fair, this is the 'correct' answer, but do you have any idea where I might start if I did decide to reinvent the wheel?!

Comment: Something as basic as setting up a staging and target server. Then dealing with connections to and from the servers.  Then figuring out how to compare the objects (pages, templates, files, etc).  Honestly, for $300/mo you can't write code that will do what Kentico Compare already does.  I bet it would take you or any dev for that matter, years of $300/mo to develop that same functionality and then you still have to maintain it too.  I'd suggest trying it out then talk with BizStream.